# Safe to delete blank postmeta?

Tags: post-meta, mysql

We have a lot of rogue custom fields. I feel that we can clear significant space in the DB if we remove the blank values. If I query my database with the following:

```
select * from wp_postmeta where meta_value = ''
```

I get 871038 (!)

My question is, is it safe to delete these? Are there any potential issues that could arise from doing this?

Comment: did you ever try this? Did it work?

Comment: Also keen to know. I am also doing it to remove the number of records....  seems like a logical choice to me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be fine deleting empty custom fields.

The main reason is, that `get_post_meta( $id, 'metakey', true )` returns an empty string if the field is not set, so it is the same as having an empty record set.

`get_post_meta( $id, 'metakey', false )`, returns an empty array if no value is set, so you should be fine too.

The only problem you could face is with getting all metadata at once (`get_post_meta( $id )`), because in the return to this call the empty values are set, but they are not set, if there is no record in the database. This could cause a few `PHP_WARNING`s, but you should be okay.

Comment: Did anyone ever do this? All check out? In the clear?

Comment: @Kody yes. part of my database cleanup.

Comment: I can confirm that it does work. I do this daily for my database! No issues so far!

Answer (score 3):

As @fischi pointed out, it should be safe to delete empty values because `get_post_meta()` returns the same value for non-existent and empty meta keys, 
unless you somehow rely on the keys being set when fetching all metadata at once.

WP 3.1 introduced the filters `add_{$meta_type}_metadata` and `update_{$meta_type}_metadata` that you can use to clean up empty values or even prevent them from being saved in the database: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/update_(meta_type)_metadata

For example, you can intercept and delete falsy values for all keys containing 'my_prefix' like this:

```
add_filter('update_post_metadata', function($check, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value) {
    if(strpos($meta_key, 'my_prefix')) {
        if(empty($meta_value)) {
            delete_post_meta($object_id, $meta_key, $prev_value);
            return true; //stop update
        }
    }
    return null; //do update 
}, 10, 5);
```

Note that this won't clean up any already existing records.

Comment: anyone tested this? Sound better than running a delete script ever day removing nulls!